# Is it possible to calculate serialized size of an object without allocating memory to hold serialized data?

Tags: kdb, q-lang

This is for a user interface to kdb, where a user can run arbitrary queries. I want to check the size of result and alert the user if it is likely to cause memory overflow on the client.

I can do

```
count -8!"my query result"
```

but I suspect that kdb will allocate a buffer to hold serialized content. Is there a way to avoid that?

Alternatively, is there a way to get memory size taken up by kdb object (internal representation), and would that be "close enough" to its serialized form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-22!<my query result>`

See http://code.kx.com/q/ref/internal/#-22x-uncompressed-length

Comment: The above link is deprected, the resource has been moved to: http://code.kx.com/q/ref/internal/#-22x-uncompressed-length

Comment: The above link has since been moved to: https://code.kx.com/q/basics/internal/#-22x-uncompressed-length